# How to use int of app delegate in other class in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, appdelegate

Can someone help me in answer below 3 question? It will help me to solve my problem.

1. How to declare `int` in `app delegate`.
2. How to transfer this `int` value to other class.
3. How to `NSLog` this value in other class.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried so far?

Comment: I used below green ticked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//  AppDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) int myIntVariable;
@end

//  ViewController.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    delegate.myIntVariable = 4;
    NSLog(@"%d", delegate.myIntVariable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare int property in AppDelegate.h as you would in any other class:

```
@property (nonatomic) int randomNumber;
```

Then import AppDelegate.h in class you would like access this variable.

And write following:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSLog(@"Int: %d", delegate.randomNumber);
```

Answer (score -2):

Create static variable in AppDelegate.h or swift. I did it in swift for this answer.

```
 static var myInt = 2
```

Then on the ViewController or other class just access it.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(AppDelegate.myInt)
}
```

You can do the instance variable but if you do so like:

```
     var myInt = 2
```

Then you need a object of AppDelegate to get the value:

```
println(AppDelegate().myInt)
```

I prefer the first one as i don't have to create object but here the AppDelegate is a singleton so either way is just fine.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Post answers in the appropriate language.